# What are the best substances for use in magnetic shielding?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I've recently become interested in magnetism and have bought a few cubic neodymium magnets to play with. I'd like to find a substance (not another magnet!) that shields against a magnetic field.

I'm not looking for shielding such as mu-metal or permalloy; these materials absorb magnetic field instead of blocking it, I'm looking for a substance that effectively blocks magnetic field from entering it, warping the magnetic field lines.

Any ideas?

Comment: Lead comes to mind.

Comment: @SolarMike You would have to cool lead down until it becomes superconducting (Meissner effect).

Comment: If you have one lying around, I heard superconductors are pretty good at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a strong diamagnet. Googling for strongest diamagnet I find 1) any superconducting material 2) pyrolytic carbon 3) bismuth. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)#Values_for_some_common_materials

Comment: Even type II superconductors?